# Am I gathering wine correctly?

Tags: endless-legend

I'm on the second quest for the [Necrophages](http://endless-legend.wikia.com/wiki/Necrophages), I'm trying to gather wine.

[image]

I've 2 cities with a wine extractor near each but I don't seem to be accumulating any wine.

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure what the problem is.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something obvious? *(probably both)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wine is a Luxury resource, not a Strategic one. So it doesn't appear in that list of resources at the top of the screen. If you open the Empire screen, you can see the luxury resources you've collected. Getting 2 per turn, you almost certainly have more than enough; head to the Unspoiled Ruins!

Comment: Turns out I had 35 wine... lol